# pgql/Hibernate File up/download - download size twice file size?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, servlets, download

i'm having trouble realizing file up/download with Java HttpServlet, Hibernate(3.5) & Postgresql Server(9.1.9)
in general the problem is when i'm uploading a file via:

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

    ServletContext servletContext = this.getServletConfig().getServletContext();
    File repository = (File) servletContext.getAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir");
    ((DiskFileItemFactory) factory).setRepository(repository);

    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    try {
        List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            byte[] dataBytes = items.get(0).get();
        Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
        SQLQuery query = session
                .createSQLQuery("SELECT nextval('test_vorgabe.seq_did')");
        Long key = ((BigInteger) query.uniqueResult()).longValue();
        session.flush();
        Datei datei = new Datei();
        datei.setDid(key);
        datei.setRevision(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        datei.setFilename(items.get(0).getName()
                );
        datei.setFile(dataBytes);
        session.save(datei);
        session.flush();

    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

which seems to be working like it should (the file size is also the same as it is on my computer)
But the problem is, when i'm downloading it - the file size is twice as it was and the file doesn't work anymore when i'm sending it back to the client.

```
        String dateiname = request.getReader().readLine();
    System.out.println("Dateiname: " + dateiname);
    dateiname = dateiname.replace("isc_TextItem_", "");
    dateiname = dateiname.substring(2);

    while (dateiname.startsWith("=")) {
        dateiname = dateiname.substring(1);
    }
    System.out.println(dateiname);
    Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Datei.class);

    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("filename", dateiname));
    Datei datei = (Datei) crit.list().get(0);
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\""
            + datei.getFilename() + "\"");
    ServletOutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();
    stream.write(datei.getFile());
    stream.flush();
    stream.close();
```

i'll also include the source of the entity bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "datei", schema = "test_vorgabe")
public class Datei implements java.io.Serializable {

private long did;
private Vorgabe vorgabe;
private String filename;
private byte[] file;
private Date revision;

public Datei() {
}

public Datei(long did, String filename, byte[] file, Date revision) {
    this.did = did;
    this.filename = filename;
    this.file = file;
    this.revision = revision;
}

public Datei(long did, Vorgabe vorgabe, String filename, byte[] file,
        Date revision) {
    this.did = did;
    this.vorgabe = vorgabe;
    this.filename = filename;
    this.file = file;
    this.revision = revision;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "did", unique = true, nullable = false)
public long getDid() {
    return this.did;
}

public void setDid(long did) {
    this.did = did;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "vid")
public Vorgabe getVorgabe() {
    return this.vorgabe;
}

public void setVorgabe(Vorgabe vorgabe) {
    this.vorgabe = vorgabe;
}

@Column(name = "filename", nullable = false)
public String getFilename() {
    return this.filename;
}

public void setFilename(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

@Column(name = "file", nullable = false)
public byte[] getFile() {
    return this.file;
}

public void setFile(byte[] file) {
    this.file = file;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "revision", nullable = false, length = 29)
public Date getRevision() {
    return this.revision;
}

public void setRevision(Date revision) {
    this.revision = revision;
}

}
```

it is saved as bytea in postgresql

can anybody help me solve this problem?

thnx in advance

Comment: Sounds like getFile() is just returning the hex-encoded bytea field. Not sure how you decode this in java, but that's where I would start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your library for connecting to PostgreSQL does not know how to decode the hex format for bytea.  You could try changing your PostgreSQL setting for bytea_output to 'escape'.  (If that works, it suggests your library is rather out of date.)

I had the same problem with Perl's DBD::Pg, only to discover that I was using a much older version than I thought I was, and after updating it then it automatically did the correct thing regardless of bytea_output setting.

Comment: @d2k which version of the driver worked for you? I think I'm getting this same problem. The DB is version 9.1 and I'm using driver version '9.1-901.jdbc4'

Comment: postgresql-9.2-1003.jdbc4